# How to add to the cart when product is its sibling

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, cart, shopping-cart, react-component

I have products and a cart on the same page. So you can imagine they both belong to the same parent (HomeScreen). So what I am trying to do is in the product component, there is an add button, and whenever it is clicked I want to show this product in the cart and the quantity should be increased, whenever I click the button.
Here is the product component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Product(props) {
  const { product } = props;
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    
  };
  return (
    <div key={product._id} className="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 product">
      <div className="card">
          <div className="image-area">

          </div>
      </div>
      <div className="products-body">
        <div className="price">${product.price}</div>
        <div className="product-name">{product.name}</div>
        <button className="add-button" onClick={addToCartHandler}>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the Cart component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addToCart } from "../../actions/cartActions";

export default function Cart(props) {
  const productId = props.match.params.added;
  const qty = 0;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty]);
  return (
    <div className="cart-box">
      <p>
        ADD TO CART : ProductID: {productId} Qty: {qty}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My cart action:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/cartConstants';

export const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);
  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      name: data.name,
      price: data.price,
      product: data.added,
      qty,
    },
  });
  localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

I don't know how to do it that's why addToCartHandler is empty. So it should be like in the image. Hope it is clear right now.

[image]